# Using VLookUp on a partial string to find associated row num from another sheet

Tags: excel

Im just trying to make a basic spreadsheet to track investments and it currently has 2 sheets. 1 sheet refreshes data from a website and the other sheet is a calculation sheet.

In the calculation sheet the following Vlookup is present
`=VLOOKUP(A3&"*", 'Refresh This File'!$A$2:$H$101, 1, FALSE)`. 
In the cell A3 the input currently is Ethereum, and the table array has the string EthereumEthereum in row 2 Col B 2nd Sheet. (the 1 argument is the row label in the other sheet)

Currently with the above formula i am getting a #N/A error.

Is there any way where i can type a partial string in the input sheet, and return the associated row num from the other sheet.

Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: Is `EthereumEthereum` in column `A`? "`the 1 argument is the row label in the other sheet`". `1`  refers to the column number in the table `$A$2:$H$101`. In your case it refers to column `A`. Also if you want the **Row Number**, you should use `MATCH` function. It gives the position of the lookup value in the array.

Comment: `EthereumEthereum` is in column B in the table `$A$2:$H$101`. in column A i have 1,2,3,4... associated with each crypto name. in this case EthereumEthereum is 2. I want to input Ethereum and have it return 2 (not the actual row number which is 3)
How would i run the MATCH statement? I currently just did `=MATCH(A3&"*", 'Refresh This File'!$A$2:$H$101,1)` [i added an extra row hence A3]. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `VLOOKUP` to work, the column in which you are looking your lookup value from should be column 1.

However you can use `INDEX` combined with `MATCH` if this is not the case:

```
=INDEX('Refresh This File'!$A$2:$A$101,MATCH(A3&"*",'Refresh This File'!$B$2:$B$101,0))
```

Comment: Not even close :) Glad to help.